Cache line management and memory ordering
I'm trying to understand how memory ordering affects to the number of writes to memory across different architectures.
Consider the following code snippet:
STR 0, [addr,0]
STR 1, [addr,1]
STR 2, [addr,2]
...
STR 7, [addr,7]

where addr is aligned to the beginning of a cache line and a cache line is 64 bytes.
So, this code is storing 8 ints to consecutive addresses in the same cache line.
Question 1:
Can stores to the same cache line can be re-ordered?
I believe that they are not for x86, but they are for ARM. Is my assumption right?
Question 2:
For this question, I'm assuming that x86 cannot reorder stores and ARM can.
A x86 CPU potentially only writes once the cache line: if the cache line is not present at the moment of the first store, it will be brought, all 64 bytes will be written, and in the future will be replaced and written back to memory.
On the other hand, a ARM CPU potentially writes 8 times the cache line:

the line [addr] is brought,
i is stored in [addr+i],
another instruction evicts the line and [addr] cache line is written back to memory,
go back to 1

Although the probability of this scenario occurring frequently is low, it's still plausible. Are there mechanisms in ARM or other architectures to mitigate such behavior?
Question 3:
Following the previous question, probably, there are mechanism to avoid writing to the same cache line multiple times back to memory in ARM architectures or other weak memory models.
So, from a memory point of view, would these architecture still see only one write per cache line for the proposed code snippet?
